# determine whether ∼ is an equivalence relation on 

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let  be the collection of rings. Define a relation ∼  on  by R~R’ if and only if there exists a ring homomorphism φ:R→R'.
(a) Determine whether the relation ∼ on  is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.
(b) Based on the findings in part (a), determine whether ∼ is an equivalence relation on .
Can you please help me?
im not sure how to begin

Comment: Isn't the relation trivial, since we always have the zero morphism $R\to R'$?

Comment: I thought that was part of the definition of homomorphism. Begin and the beginning.  Reflexive is there a homomorphim between a ring and itself.  Yes, the identity.  Symetric if there is a homomorphism between S and R is there one between R and S? Yes, the inverse.  ANd so on.

Comment: fleablood, homomorphisms may lack well-defined inverses (e.g. the zero morphism Luiz mentioned). I am guessing the question may involve isomorphism instead of homomorphism (or should).

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just prove that a ring isomorphism is an equivalence relation. Then since every ring isomorphism is a ring homomorphism, the homomorphism properties hold for each reflexive, symmetric and transitive arguments?

Comment: Basically, you're arguing that if a relation contains an equivalence relation, it is an equivalence relation itself. But then it would follow that every reflexive relation is necessarily an equivalence relation (because it contains equality relation).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your rings (and, more importantly, ring homomorphisms) are unital. Otherwise, the question would be trivial (as you always have the zero homomorphism).

A technical problem is that usually (by definition) a relation is defined on a set, making the question meaningless.

If you ignore that (or restrict yourself to a set of rings), showing reflexivity and transitivity should be trivial (really, just write it down). However, symmetry does not hold: consider ${\bf Z}$ and ${\bf Q}$.